# Mongodb design for speed

Tags: mongodb, performance, collections

Consider data that are related like:

```
users (± 100.000)

hotels (± 20.000)
   ---| rooms (± 100 per hotel)
       ---| remarks (0 or 1 per user per room, editable)
       ---| discussion (0 to ˜ per user per room, add-only)

resorts
   ---| apartments
       ---| remarks (0 or 1 per user per apartment)
       ---| discussion (0 to ˜ per user per apartment)

campings
      idem
```

**Questions for the database are:**

• Find a hotel/resort/... with certain specs

• Find a room/apartment/... with certain specs

**... but most important:**

• Find *hotels* connected to *rooms* that have specific *remarks*.

I've experimented on Atlas with a flat setup. So different collections for hotels, rooms, remarks and discussions. I found out that right-joins are most time consuming for Mongo.

**My questions are about performance:**

• Should I make the collection setup in Mongodb as discribed above, so with sub and subsub collections? Or flat? Or is there another setup possible? What is best-practice?

• How can I get the best speed from Mongo. Is it best-practice to get all query data in one single request, or to use several requests and join/combine stuff in Python?

Thanks. This is a fun ride ;-)

Comment: I would but hotels, rooms, remarks and discussions all in one collection

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: why?

Comment: Document orient NoSQL databases like MongoDB are not optimized for joins, some NoSQL databases do not even support joins at all. Thus embedded objects would be better provided the sizes are not getting too big. Don't design relational data for a non-relational database.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: Thankt for the help. Two things. 

One: I did not need to ask Why, after looking at your status here at Stackoverflow. You clearly are a Mongdb expert. My apologies for that.

Two: I ran some queries with the database in Flat and in Tree structure. The difference was huge: factor 10+ faster in Tree than Flat.

So again: thanks.

Comment: No, your question is absolutely fine - you are a beginner and I was a lazy guy when I wrote my comment. I should have added some explanations.